# Retrieving a word from a String

Tags: java, string

I have this line:

```
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = XXX)(HOST = YYY)(PORT = ZZZ))
```

that I need to retrieve the `HOST` name which is in this case `YYY`.

I don't know if it will be written in *lowercase* or *uppercase* or even a mix between them.
So I switch the whole line to uppercase by `line.toUpperCase()` and then I split the line according to `HOST =` and I pick the characters until I get `)` which indicates the end of the host name.

I'm sure there is a better way to do this. Any hints will be appreciated.

My code:

```
String host = "";
line = line.toUpperCase();
int i = line.indexOf("HOST");
while(line.charAt(i)!='=')
    i++;
while(line.charAt(i)!=')') {
    i++;
    if(line.charAt(i)!=')'&&line.charAt(i)!=' ')
       host = host + line.charAt(i);
}
return host;
```

Comment: Why to do all lowercase and uppercase thing if you are matching `)`?

Comment: I'm not matching `)`. I need to find the word right next to the `HOST` word which is not guaranteed to be in lower/upper case. But I know that this word ends when there is a ')'.

Comment: Your approach seems reasonable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
    String s= "(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = XXX)(HOST = YYY)(PORT = ZZZ)) }";
    String host = s.replaceAll("^.+\\((HOST|host) *= *(.+?)\\).+$", "$2");
```

Comment: Very elegant. I haven't think of a regex solution. Thanks

Comment: Is there a way to make this work even if the `=` is attached to `HOST`? (`HOST=YYY`)

Comment: This will not work if `HOST` is written in lowercase (`host`).

Comment: Can anybody please comment on my solution? Your suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

You can use apache.commons [**StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(Str)**](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#containsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

```
 StringUtils.contains("abc", "A"); //returns true
```

Comment: Great one. I guess that I can achieve this by `line.toUpperCase().contains(stringToCheck.toUpperCase())`

Comment: And by that.. how exactly will you "retrieve the HOST name which is in this case YYY"? I'm SO lost...

Comment: @ManuelMiranda Still didn't.. by that I only get that line which contains the `HOST` word.. (I already did it but didn't mentioned it in the question)

Answer (score 3):

What about:

```
String host = line.toUpperCase().split("HOST = ")[1].split(")")[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you use [substringbetween()](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#substringBetween%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) Of StringUtils

```
substringBetween(str,"(HOST=",")");
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will give you host name,be your string in any case(upper, lower or mix)

```
String[] st= str.split("=");
        String[] st2= st[3].split("\\)\\(");
        System.out.println("Host name::"+st2[0]);
```

str will be the whole string... And there would be no need for you to convert the whole string to uppercase or lowercase... :)

Answer (score 0):

You only need the HOST. OK.
But having a step in regex you can use this :

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\s*\\(ADDRESS\\s*=\\s*\\(\\s*PROTOCOL\\s*=\\s*(\\w+)\\s*\\)\\s*\\(\\s*HOST\\s*=\\s*(\\w+)\\s*\\)\\s*\\(\\s*PORT\\s*=\\s*(\\d+)\\s*\\)\\s*\\)\\s*");
Matcher m = p.matcher("(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = http)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 8080))");
if(m.matches()){
    System.out.println("protocol = "+m.group(1));
    System.out.println("host = "+m.group(2));
    System.out.println("port = "+m.group(3));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as the format of you string remains as it is, the solution is far simple :

```
line.split("\\)\\(")[1].split("=")[1].trim();
```

Also, the case of the string does not matter in this case!

Comment: The problem is that the order of props can be different, eg (HOST = YYY)(PROTOCOL = XXX)(PORT = ZZZ) :(

Comment: The "order of props" is not a criteria in the question

Comment: You are right, it's not there, and in this sense your solution works fine. But other solutions allow parameter reordering which is good anyway.

Comment: I thought of this solution as it is also case independent under the given scenarios.

Comment: Actually I saw that it was about Oracle addreess config string which accepts params in any order, so I didnt even think whether reordering was in the requirements or not